# Installing torchaudio in Windows

Tags: python, pytorch, sox, libsox

I am trying to install `torchaudio` in Windows from source. I installed sox and added it in the path env variable. Then I run

```
python setup.py install
```

cloned from the GitHub. When I import torchaudio, I get warning

> No audio backend is available.

I think this means that the sox is not configured correctly or I have done something very wrong. How to install torchaudio in Windows? My Linux machine is not good and I can't use Linux which has CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the backend.
On Windows it's PySoundFile

```
pip install PySoundFile
```

This should do the trick
You can follow torch documentation here
https://pytorch.org/audio/backend.html